# When connecting to owncloud i get 'You are accessing the server from an untrusted domain'

Tags: docker, docker-compose, owncloud

Just installed owncloud using the instructions in https://doc.owncloud.com/server/next/admin_manual/installation/docker/ and when I try to connect to the server from my machine I get the following error message...

```
You are accessing the server from an untrusted domain.
Please contact your administrator. If you are an administrator of this instance, configure the "trusted_domains" setting in config/config.php. An example configuration is provided in config/config.sample.php or at the documentation.
```

IK what the error message means and how I would normally fix it in a standard apache setup, but how do I change these in the docker images?

I tried changing the line OWNCLOUD_TRUSTED_DOMAINS in the .env file to a wildcard (originally it said localhost) and that did not help.

Comment: What did you change the variable to and what is the url you try to access your instance with? Note that you can not use an IP as trusted *domain* and thus won't be able to access ownCloud just via an IP.

Comment: I changed it to * (wildcard), originally it said localhost. I was trying to access it via it's IP address http://x.x.x.x:8080

Comment: Problem fixed... changed OWNCLOUD_DOMAIN and 
OWNCLOUD_TRUSTED_DOMAINS to be the IP address of the owncloud server itself and it worked.